# Recursive globbing of fast-changing directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob, pathlib

I stumbled upon unintuitive problem: if you recursively glob (with pathlib) fast-changing directory, where other directories are created and deleted, you have a chance to get `FileNotFoundException`. If directory is not found, then why bother me with this? Why not just skip bogus directory and continue? And how i can get around this in a compact way?

Here is how to reproduce this:

Launch one terminal with this sh command

```
while true; do mkdir deleteme && rmdir deleteme; done
```

and another with this python script:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path()
while True:
    list(p.rglob('*'))
```

or, as oneliner:

```
while true; do mkdir 1 && rmdir 1; done & python3 -c "from pathlib import Path; from itertools import count; p = Path(); [list(p.rglob('*')) for i in count(start=1)]"; fg
```

Comment: have you tried a `try:
  list(p.rglob('*'))
except FileNotFoundException:
  continue
`

Comment: it's not an option, i need everything that can give me rglob. If it will be interuppted, i need to start it again.

Comment: Since it sounds like you need speec pathlib isn't exactly the fastest. If you are not bound to using rglob, have a look at this https://github.com/juancarlospaco/thatlib#thatlib

Comment: maybe that's a situation people on serverfault or unix are more familiar with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive generating the exception is `os.scandir`.

What is happening is the `pathlib.Path.rglob()` method makes a selector object (`pathlib._WildcardSelector` via `pathlib._make_selector`, given your pattern), and then this is lazily iterated over during the execution of the `rglob()` generator.

The `pathlib` module doesn't seem to give any hooks to readily customize or override this behavior.

The best solution would probably be to subclass the `Path` or `PosixPath` class, override the `rglob()` method, rebuilding the implementation in a way that is resilient to this error mode.

A monkey patch method that seems to work as a proof of concept:

```
import contextlib
import pathlib

def my_scandir(path=None):
     while True:
         try:
             result = list(os.scandir(path))
         except FileNotFoundError:
             continue
         @contextlib.contextmanager
         def wrapped_result():
             try:
                 yield result
             finally:
                 pass
         return wrapped_result()

pathlib._NormalAccessor.scandir = staticmethod(my_scandir)
```

After this patch is applied, the while loop with `rglob('*')` in your example no longer fails with `FileNotFoundError`.

This works on Python v3.8.5. Because it uses implementation details of the pathlib module, it may not work on other python versions.

Answer (score 0):

- Adding Another possible solution
- If your fast changing directories contain hidden files/directories (i.e directories starting with a `.` in unix file systems
- Then you can use `glob.glob` or `glob.iglob` rather than `pathlib.Path.glob`
- `glob.glob` ignores hidden files/directories by default. So it won't break if the hidden files/directories get deleted halfway through the scan
- this will work for example with programs that use file staging to create hidden files. E.g pyspark creates .spark-staging files